# What are is_published and is_schema_published columns in sys.objects view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am looking for information about is_published and is_schema_published columns

```
select * from sys.objects
```

Comment: This is a product specific question. Tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: And assuming this is SQL Server, what version (2008, 2012, 2014)?

Comment: Added version information, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
These two columns of "sys.Objects" is used in replication .
If is_published = 1 then object is used in replication .
```

[Reference](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic913057-291-1.aspx)